# How we can have the real color on an picture thumbnail when we click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

For my project here I tried to have a color picture when I clicked on one of the four different pictures. [image: picture of the project]

The four different picture are thumbnails, and when I click on a thumbnail, this one is active and I want to have this active thumbnail with the right logo color, like the Photoshop profile here. And the other Thumbnails and in grey, because we didn't click on it so they are considered inactive.

So I tried to do this with filter property and I didn't find the right solution.
So can you help me please to find the right solution?

I can show you my code of my project :

```js
Vue.component('carousel', {
    template: `
        <div class="card-carousel" >
            <div class="thumbnails">
               
                <div 
                v-for="(image, index) in images" 
                :key="image.id" 
                :class="['thumbnail-image', (activeImage == index) ? 'active' : '']" 
                @click="activateImage(index)"> 
                <img :src="image.thumb" class="active"/>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containe-carousel">

                <span id = "textespan"> {{currentImage.text}}</span>
            <div class="photoshop-screenshot">                
            <img :src="currentImage.big"  alt="">
                    
            </div>
            <div class="card-img">
                <img :src="currentImage2.big2" alt="">
                   

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    computed: {

        currentImage() {
            return this.images[this.activeImage];
        },

        currentImage2() {
            return this.images[this.activeImage];
        }
     
    },

        data() {
            return {
                activeImage: 0,
            
            }
        },

        methods: {     
            activateImage(imageIndex) {
                this.activeImage = imageIndex;
            },  
            
        
        },
    
        props: ['images']
    });
```

```css
.section{
    background-color: black;
}

.card-carousel {
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
}

.containe-carousel {
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.thumbnails {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: row;

}

.thumbnail-image {
    display: fixed;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px;

}

.thumbnail-image > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 250ms;
    filter:  grayscale(100%);

}

.thumbnail-image:selected> img {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    visibility: hidden;
    filter: none;
}


.card-img { 
    position: relative;
}

 .card-img > img {
   
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 7%;
    z-index: 2; 
}

 .photoshop-screenshot {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 65%;
    left:50%;top:75%;
 
}

.active{ 
    filter:    contrast(1000%)
    /* black to white */
    invert(100%)
    /* white to off-white */
    sepia(100%)
    /* off-white to yellow */
    saturate(10000%)
    /* do whatever you want with yellow */
    hue-rotate(90deg);

}

#textespan {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 300%;
}

.containe-carousel span {
    
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
         
        <section class="section" id="app">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center" style="margin:0px 50px">
                    <div class="heading-underscore">
                        <h2 class="dk-5q-color">
                             <?php say("X50Q-dashboard-title"); ?>
                         </h2> 
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="columns">
                     <div class="column "> 
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <carousel
                                :starting-image="0"
                                :show-progress-bar="true"
                                :images="images"     
                            ></carousel>
                    
                        </div>   
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>            
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
    
<script src ="/x/x50q-rgb-mechanical-keyboard/x50q-cloud-js.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() { 
                
                return {
                    images: [
                       
                        {
                            text : 'Photoshop',
                            id: '1',
                            big: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/photoshop-profile.PNG',
                            big2: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/photoshop-screenshot.png',
                            thumb: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/photoshop-logo.jpg'
                        },
                        {
                            text : 'Aurocad',
                            id: '2',
                            big: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/autocad-profile.png',
                            big2: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/autocad-screenshot.png',
                            thumb: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/autocad-logo.png'
                        },
                        {
                            text : ' Counter-Strike',
                            id: '3',
                            big: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/counterstrike-profile.png',
                            big2: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/counterstrike-screenshot.jpg',
                            thumb: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/counterstrike-logo.png'
                        },
                        {
                            text : 'League of Legends',
                            id: '4',
                            big: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/leagueoflegends-profile.png',
                            big2: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/leagueoflegends-screenshot.png',
                            thumb: '/images/das-keyboard-x50q/leagueoflegends-logo.jpg'
                        }
                    ],
                    
                
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The console is throwing a lot of errors in that demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem 1: `.active` filter does not remove grayscale

When the image is clicked, you apply an `.active` class, which applies an exaggerated filter (making it look like a photo negative) instead of removing the grayscale:

```
.active {
    filter:    contrast(1000%)
    /* black to white */
    invert(100%)
    /* white to off-white */
    sepia(100%)
    /* off-white to yellow */
    saturate(10000%)
    /* do whatever you want with yellow */
    hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

The CSS should be either:

```
filter: grayscale(0);
```

OR to remove all filters:

```
filter: none;
```

#### Problem 2: All thumbnails are `.active`

While the `.active` class is dynamically added to `.thumbnail-image`, it's also statically applied to all thumbnails (the `img` child element). This will make all images appear in the "active" state all the time. The static class should be removed:

```
<!-- <img :src="image.thumb" class="active"/> --> <!-- DON'T DO THIS -->
<img :src="image.thumb">
```

*Alternatively, you can move the dynamic setting of `.thumbnail-image` and `.active` from the container `div` to the `img` itself.*

#### Problem 3: `.active` does not target `img`

The `.active` class is applied to `.thumbnail-image` (the `img` container), but you really want to apply the filter to the `img` child element, so you'll have to modify your CSS selector to this:

```
.active > img {
  ...
}
```

*If you opted to move the dynamic class setting to the `img` itself (as suggested previously above), you don't have to modify the selector here.*

#### Demo of fix

```js
Vue.component("carousel", {
  template: `
        <div class="card-carousel" >
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <div v-for="(image, index) in images" 
                    :key="image.id" 
                    :class="['thumbnail-image', (activeImage == index) ? 'active' : '']" 
                    @click="activateImage(index)"> 
                  <img :src="image.thumb" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containe-carousel">
                <span id="textespan"> {{currentImage.text}}</span>
                <div class="photoshop-screenshot">
                  <img :src="currentImage.big"  alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card-img">
                  <img :src="currentImage2.big2" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
  computed: {
    currentImage() {
      return this.images[this.activeImage];
    },

    currentImage2() {
      return this.images[this.activeImage];
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      activeImage: 0
    };
  },

  methods: {
    activateImage(imageIndex) {
      this.activeImage = imageIndex;
    }
  },

  props: ["images"]
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    images: [
      {
        text: "Photoshop",
        id: "1",
        big: "//placekitten.com/201/201",
        big2: "//placekitten.com/201/201",
        thumb: "//placekitten.com/201/201"
      },
      {
        text: "Aurocad",
        id: "2",
        big: "//placekitten.com/202/202",
        big2: "//placekitten.com/202/202",
        thumb: "//placekitten.com/202/202"
      },
      {
        text: " Counter-Strike",
        id: "3",
        big: "//placekitten.com/203/203",
        big2: "//placekitten.com/203/203",
        thumb: "//placekitten.com/203/203"
      },
      {
        text: "League of Legends",
        id: "4",
        big: "//placekitten.com/204/204",
        big2: "//placekitten.com/204/204",
        thumb: "//placekitten.com/204/204"
      }
    ]
  })
});
```

```css
.section {
  background-color: black;
}

.card-carousel {
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
}

.containe-carousel {
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.thumbnail-image {
  display: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail-image > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 250ms;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.thumbnail-image:selected > img {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  visibility: hidden;
  filter: none;
}

.card-img {
  position: relative;
}

.card-img > img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 7%;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* .photoshop-screenshot {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 75%;
} */

.active > img {
/*   filter: contrast(1000%) invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%)
    hue-rotate(90deg); */
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

#textespan {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
}

.containe-carousel span {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<section class="section" id="app">
  <carousel :starting-image="0"
            :show-progress-bar="true"
            :images="images"></carousel>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you for your complete explanation, I correctly understand  my different mistakes, and you code works too.

Comment: @ShirleyTruffier-Blanc No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need CSS.

```
.thumbnail-image > img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.thumbnail-image > img:active {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Comment: yes I already did this but I want the color stay on my picture when I click on it, and that's the real problem, the color does not stay on the picture in this case

Comment: @ShirleyTruffier-Blanc What do you mean by "color does not stay on the picture"? Is the intention to allow more than one active/color item at a time?

Comment: @tony19 my intention is that when I click on one of the 4 photos it appears in color and that the color is always present after I click on the image. And meanwhile the other images are in black and white, and when I click on another image is displayed in color and the others in black and white and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class without `grayscale`, and normal tag img with `grayscale`. Add class without grayscale,`color` in my example, for the clicked element, and iterate for others images and remove color class. Like this:

```js
function onClick(it) {
 
  const withColor = it.parentElement
    .getElementsByClassName('color')[0];
    
  if(withColor)
    withColor.classList.remove('color');
    
  it.classList.add( 'color' );
  
  
}
```

```css
#images {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  filter: grayscale( 100% );
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

img.color {
  filter: grayscale( 0% );
  transition: filter 400ms;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 2px
}
```

```html
<div id="images">

   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MagOw.jpg" class="image" onclick="onClick(this)">
   
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MagOw.jpg" class="image" onclick="onClick(this)">
   
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MagOw.jpg" class="image" onclick="onClick(this)">
   
   

</div>
```